# php mysql query with a loop in it

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

I'm trying to retrieve the results of users in my database, and then if my checkbox is selected to retrieve only users who have photos to show those results, but I can't seem to figure out how to loop through those results or if I am even doing it in the right context.
    `

```
$photos = $_POST['pcbox'];
$basicsql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$basicsql .= "WHERE status > '1'";
if($photos=='1'){
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM pictures GROUP BY user_id");
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    $options[] = " AND (users.user_id = '$row2[user_id]')";
    foreach($options as $key => $str){
        $basicsql .= $str;
    }
}
$basicsql .= " ORDER BY users.last_login DESC";
$pagesql = mysql_query($basicsql);
```

All works until the checkbox is selected

Comment: Is there really a quote missing at the end of the 3rd line ? Or is it really your code ? I'm not sure if I should correct that.

Comment: I forgot it on placing this example.

Comment: Unfortunately it's too short a fix to get past the minimum edit length!

Comment: @PhilLello: Then I'm not sure how I just edited it..?

Comment: @Tomalak Must be different for peer-review-edits and full-edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same db handle for nested loops. You need to explicitly set the db handle for each one.

However, you can just do it in one sql query.

Observe:

`Select * from users u inner join pictures p on u.id=p.user_id 
where status > 1`

An INNER JOIN will give you only users that have rows in the pictures table.

This will give you users that have pictures only.

**Edit**

This will give the number of pitcures and only 1 user row.

`Select name,email,address,status,count(*) as num_pics from users u inner join pictures p on u.id=p.user_id group by  name,email,address,status
where status > 1`

Comment: I've tried that way, but then if the user has more then one picture it repeats the user as many times has they have pictures.

Comment: Ok, well I ended up figuring it out by just adding `if($photos=='1'){ $basicsql .= ""; }` a couple times through out the areas I needed to achieve this.

Comment: @Bobby: `$basicsql .= "";` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yeah I know, what I ended up doing was...
 `$basicsql = "SELECT *,users.user_id FROM users";`
 `if($photos=='1'){`
 `$basicsql .= ", pictures";`
 `}`
 `$basicsql .= " WHERE status > '1'`
 `if($photos=='1'){`
 `$basicsql .= " AND (users.user_id = pictures.user_id)";`
 `$basicsql .= " GROUP BY users.user_id";`
 `}`
 `$basicsql .= " ORDER BY users.last_login DESC";`
 `$pagesql = mysql_query($basicsql);`

Comment: I'd use my solution because  it is more efficient and simpler to understand. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this is what you're looking for. Untested as well.

```
$photos = $_POST['pcbox'];
$basicsql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE status > 1";
$photoSql = "SELECT * FROM users, pictures WHERE status > 1 AND users.user_id = pictures.user_id GROUP BY users.user_id ORDER BY users.last_login DESC"

if($photos=='1')
{
    $result = mysql_query($photosSql);
}
else
{
    $result = mysql_query($photoSql);
}
```

Comment: You can't select * and only group by user.id

Comment: You meant `$basicsql` in the second clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
$photos = isset($_POST['pcbox']) ? $_POST['pcbox'] : null;

$sql = 'SELECT U.* FROM users AS U LEFT JOIN pictures AS P ON P.user_id = U.id ' . ($photos == '1' ? 'WHERE P.id IS NOT NULL') . ' GROUP BY U.id ORDER BY U.last_login DESC';

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  // Do something with the user info, such as outputting it to a table
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Furthermore, close while before start looping in options.

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Comment: Not a problem.. now you know :)